# Request Mapping in Spring MVC Controller hitting twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/form")
public String formForCreate(Model model) {
log("Action 'formForCreate'");   
}
```

Above mentioned Request Mapping is hitting twice. How can I stop this .?

Comment: How do you measure it is hitting twice? Isn't it simply a misconfiguration of your logging (login twice).

Comment: Share some more code, error messages, console output...

Comment: Question need some details. Sure you aren't calling it twice ? Perhaps it reloads the page ? Perhaps the page loads as default and reloads when you go to Url ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could check is if your application context that scans for controller components is being loaded twice. For example say in your web xml you configured the dispatcher servlet to be named dispatcher in your web.xml and you configured the contextConfigLocation to load the following bean config files.

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>classpath*:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This could results in the controller getting hit twice per request becuase the dispatcher-servlet is automatically loaded once when the dispatcher servlet starts up and another time when the ContextLoaderListener starts up.

Comment: Abdelhak is correct. Check if your RequestMappings are initialized twice when the server is loaded up. It might be the result of a misconfiguration wherein you load all beans twice (two applicationcontexts, e.g.).

Comment: A controller won't get hit twice. If there were two beans registered for the same type, they'd have the same `@RequestMapping` and Spring MVC would complain about duplicate mappings and crash, @Schaka . Spring only uses one handler for each request.